# Delete all worksheets after X amount of sheets

Tags: vba, excel

My code below should delete all sheets, from 6 onwards, however many there may be, when this button is pressed.

It works, however I am getting 'Delete Method of Worksheet class failed' error afterwards

```
   Private Sub UnloadButton_Click()

    Do While Worksheets.Count > 5
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(6).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Similar questions I have seen want to delete all sheets or named sheets and I couldn't really adapt them to this.

I suspected it was because it was trying to delete sheet 6 when sheet 6 no longer exists, but surely once sheet count is 5, it will not trigger another loop?

Comment: Code works for me.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Yes, just tried it in a completely new sheet and it works. I don't have any hidden sheets on the original. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Is your button on a sheet that might get deleted?

Comment: Try to `debug.print worksheets.count` in your loop just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David G

I had 3 'Very hidden" sheets that needed to be removed first as my code was indeed actually trying to delete hidden sheets.

Important lesson when working on another users sheet, check for very hidden sheets.

Answer (score 1):

While your issue was `VeryHidden` note that you can delete sheets without looping as below

Also in your original code, suggest you move the   `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` outside your loop.

```
 If Worksheets.Count > 5 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          Sheets(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("=ROW(6:" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Index & ")"))).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End If
```